# How to monitor Ejabberd server's statistics through Nagios, Grapherl, Grafite or any other?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, nagios

I am currently looking for Ejabberd monitoring tool. There are certain ejabberd modules like grafite, statsfxd and statsd but i get error when i enable them. Alos the ejabberd official site states that the server is configurable with Nagios monitoring but i could not find any nagios plugin for monitoring ejabberd. Can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any out-of-the-box solutions for this. You'll have to create your own.

One of the simpler solutions is to write a Bash script to use ejabberdctl to export server statistics to a web-accessible file, then use Prometheus's blackbox-exporter to scrape that file and get its metrics into Prometheus.